# Compilation Error -The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a component class which is a singleton class. 
For accessing the singleton instance I do this:

```
instance = new Global();
```

And return the instance. The constructor is private. The global class is **public sealed class**.

Now I drop an image list control on to the designer of this component class and the designer.cs file is generated. The global class in the designer file is **internal class**

Now I am getting this error at `instance = new Global()` line. The call is ambiguous between following methods or properties.

What it is that I am missing??

Comment: Can you show the full error message, and the full line of code it happens on?

Comment: Provide enough code for us to be able to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just means that it can find two types called Global, and it doesn't know thich one to use.

This generally happens when a class is found in two namespaces, both included in the file.

There are a couple of ways to fix this:

- Specify the full namespace when creating it like `new The.Full.Namespace.Global()`
- Or create a [namespace alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx) and the specify using that.

  `using shortendName = The.Full.Namespace.;`
  `new shortendName.Global();`
- Or remove the confusion by removing one of the namespace includes (of course if you need both this isn't appropriate)